# Beer evening in Berlin?

Tags: discussion, social-networking

[image: Quack]

Among the Berliner members of the community: Would you like to get together and have a beer evening? We'll have plenty of time to talk about TeX and become friends ;)

I suggest to have (at least) two answers to this questions:

1. List of participants. If you want to join, then upvote and add your (nick)name.
2. Organizational answer(s). How to find a date, place etc.

So, who's in?

Comment: Woohoo! I'd love to go, but it's quite far from where I live (namely, in a country overseas). `:(` Congrats for the initiative! I hereby declare to whom it may concern that percusse is my official representant and may have as many beers or alcoholic beverages as he well pleases, for he's my buddy, and I probably owe him lots of etilic stuff. `:)`

Comment: See http://projekte.dante.de/Stammtische/Berlin :-)

Comment: Damnnn, that is a good idea. Perhaps we can have one in San Jose, California as well some day.  Hey, can we vote down those people we don't want to come? :-)

Comment: Talk about TeX after drinking a few pitchers of Berliner Weiße? What a pity that I do not understand German.

Comment: @Fran: I believe this kind of get together should be in English....

Answer (score 9):

There is already a regular (monthly) get-together of TeXies in Berlin (more Information is [here](http://projekte.dante.de/Stammtische/Berlin)) and I'm sure you can get beer there.

Comment: It seems like the link is not really updated. Might be better: http://mlists.in-berlin.de/mailman/listinfo/tex-stammtisch-mlists.in-berlin.de

Answer (score 7):

Would like to have beer!

Please add your (nick)name in case you want, tentatively, to participate.

1. Dror

Comment: I'm local, but I'll be out of Berlin most of the time until August.  I'll ask what's up when I get back.